# Powershell Script to deploy multiple software using variables

Tags: windows, powershell, configuration, designer

I am building a deployment script to install software on a new device using a ppkg file.

The script looks at which drive is the USB drive and copies the software over to the local temp folder and runs them according to a set of variables as shown below.

What I am struggling to do is simplify the script so I am not repeating code 7 times down the page, I want to just run a loop 7 times to pull in the needed software. I tried an array but I think I am not quite understanding it completely.

This is my script so far with the repeating code:

```
#SOE application Variables

#applcation1 CM_client
$app1name = "Config Manager Client 1706"
$app1skip = "no"
$app1path = "$env:SystemDrive\temp\soe\application_installs\app1\CM_client_inst_1706\"
$app1runcommand = "clientx64.bat"
$app1arguments = ""
#applcation2
$app2name = "Office 2016 Pro Plus"
$app2skip = "no"
$app2path = "$env:SystemDrive\temp\soe\application_installs\app2\O2016\"
$app2runcommand = "setup.exe"
$app2arguments = "/configure configuration.xml"
#log Folder
$datetime = Get-Date -format "yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss"
$logpath = "$env:ALLUSERSPROFILE\SOEInst_ppkg\$datetime"
New-Item -Path $logpath -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Transcript Start
Start-Transcript -Path $logpath\SOE-app-installer-ppkg-$datetime.log

#Timer Function
$pkgremovetime = Get-Date -format "HH:mm:ss"
write-host "Script Start Time - $pkgremovetime"

#Find USB Drive
Write-host Discovering USB Drive

$drives = (GET-WMIOBJECT –query “SELECT * from win32_logicaldisk").DeviceID

foreach ($drive in $drives) {

            $usbdrive = (dir $drive USBIMG.FILE | Select-Object -Unique "USBIMG.FILE")
            if ($usbdrive -match "USBIMG.FILE*") {
                    $datadrive = $drive
                    }
            }

Write-host Found $datadrive is the USB drive

#Copy Applications to Local Drive
Write-Host Creating Installer Folder
New-Item -Path $env:SystemDrive\temp\SOE -ItemType Directory
Copy-Item $datadrive\application_installs $env:SystemDrive\temp\soe -Recurse -Verbose

#Install Applications
#Application 1
    if ($app1skip -eq "no") {
    if ($app1arguments) { #Arguments Variable Populated
        Write-Host Installing Applcation 1 `($app1name`)
        $app1 = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $app1path$app1runcommand -ErrorAction Continue -ArgumentList $app1arguments -WindowStyle Normal
            if ($app1.ExitCode -eq "0") {
                Write-Host $app1name Installed ok
                } Else {
                    Write-host $app1name install exited with code $app1.ExitCode
                    } 
                }
            }Else { #Argurments Variable Empty
                Write-Host Installing Applcation 1 `($app1name`)
                $app1 = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $app1path$app1runcommand -ErrorAction Continue -WindowStyle Normal
                if ($app1.ExitCode -eq "0") {
                    Write-Host $app1name Installed ok
                    } Else {
                        Write-host $app1name install exited with code $app1.ExitCode
                }
            }


#Application 2
if ($app2skip -eq "no") {
    if ($app2arguments) { #Arguments Variable Populated
        Write-Host Installing Applcation 2 `($app2name`)
        $app2 = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $app2path$app2runcommand -ErrorAction Continue -ArgumentList $app2arguments -WindowStyle Normal
            if ($app2.ExitCode -eq "0") {
                Write-Host $app2name Installed ok
                } Else {
                    Write-host $app2name install exited with code $app2.ExitCode
                    } 
                }
            }Else { #Argurments Variable Empty
                Write-Host Installing Applcation 2 `($app2name`)
                $app2 = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $app2path$app2runcommand -ErrorAction Continue -WindowStyle Normal
                if ($app2.ExitCode -eq "0") {
                    Write-Host $app2name Installed ok
                    } Else {
                        Write-host $app2name install exited with code $app2.ExitCode
                }
            }
#cleanup

Remove-Item $env:SystemDrive\temp\soe -Recurse -Force -Verbose

#get end time
$pkgremovetime_end = Get-Date -format "HH:mm:ss"

#calculate time difference
$timetaken = New-TimeSpan $pkgremovetime $pkgremovetime_end
    if ($timetaken.Seconds -lt 0) {
$Hrs = ($timetaken.Hours) + 23
$Mins = ($timetaken.Minutes) + 59
$Secs = ($timetaken.Seconds) + 59 }
    else {
$Hrs = $timetaken.Hours
$Mins = $timetaken.Minutes
$Secs = $timetaken.Seconds }
$Difference = '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f $Hrs,$Mins,$Secs

#log time difference
write-host "Script End Time - $pkgremovetime_end"
Write-Host "Total time taken $difference"

#Transcript End
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: You couldn't distill this down to a small representative sample instead of a 100+ line code dump?

Comment: Cut it down for you, as best to represent what its doing, hope that makes you happy.....

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Please stop putting the Javascript/HTML code formatting back after I take it off. This isn't Javascript or HTML. For regular code, use the **{}** button on the toolbar. Thanks.

Comment: To be honest this looks more like a https://codereview.stackexchange.com question than a SO question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make a function which takes in the variables. I did a quick comparison of your installation codes and something like this should work

```
function installApplication{
    Param($skip, $arguments, $name, $path, $runcommand)
    if ($skip -eq "no"){
        if ($arguments){
            write-host "Installing Application $appname"
            $app = Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $path$runcommand -ErrorAction....
            if($app.ExitCode -eq "0"){
            ....
            ....
}
```

and so on, You can then call the function using

```
installApplication $app1skip $app1arguments $app1name $app1path $app1runcommand
installApplication $app2skip $app2arguments $app2name $app2path $app1runcommand
```

Your input arguments will replace the function parameters in the order you pass them in, or you can use -skip $app1skip to assign the parameters.

If your repeating the same code too many times, I suggest throwing it into something like diffchecker, put the code into a function and replace all the differences with variables.

You can see your code here https://www.diffchecker.com/FxAIdD6g (1 Day only)

Comment: I will give that a try, looks like a very nice solution thanks.  I found some other issues in my code and cleaned it up will look into the function.